# Ketone bodies vs glycogen cycle

Tags: energy, carbohydrate, ketogenic-diet

I'm doing some analysis about the body deriving energy from ketones vs glycogen. I'm looking for data about how much more/less (I'm guessing less) ketone use is vs glycogen in terms of oxygen consumption. I know our body's RQ when running off fat (i.e, ketone bodies) is .70 vs 1 on glycogen, but how does the cycle look? How do ketones actually turn into ATP? How much oxygen is consumed in that process?

Comment: Have you read Wikipedia on [Citric_acid_cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid_cycle) and
 [Energy Pathways or chapter 3 of Nutrition for Health, Fitness, and Sport, 7/e](http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/dl/free/0072441704/152842/sample_ch03.pdf)  ?

Comment: related: [How does one train for sports when the three metabolic pathways interact?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3463/how-does-one-train-for-sports-when-the-three-metabolic-pathways-interact)

Comment: related: [Metabolic Equations for Anaerobic Exercise?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14961/metabolic-equations-for-anaerobic-exercise?lq=1)